# Validating entities using data annotations or fluent api in EF 7.0 (In Memory)

Tags: unit-testing, data-annotations, mstest, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I can't verify and test my database by in memory providers.
for example I set these properties to required :

```cs
public abstract class Log
{
    #region Properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ClientIp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Application { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Host { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Method { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

and this is my DBContext :

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUsers, Role, Guid>, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var useInMemoryDatabase = _configuration[key: "UseInMemoryDatabase"].Equals(value: "true",
            comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (useInMemoryDatabase)
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
        else
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                connectionString: _configuration[key: "ConnectionStrings:ApplicationDbContextConnection"]
                , sqlServerOptionsAction: serverDbContextOptionsBuilder =>
                {
                    var minutes = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalSeconds;
                    serverDbContextOptionsBuilder.CommandTimeout(commandTimeout: minutes);
                });
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Log>()
            .HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Log>()
            .HasDiscriminator<int>(name: "Type")
            .HasValue<LogRequest>(value: Convert.ToInt32(value: LogLevel.Information))
            .HasValue<LogError>(value: Convert.ToInt32(value: LogLevel.Error));


    }
```

And this is my unit test :

```cs
[TestClass]
public class LogRepositoryTest
{


  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public LogRepositoryTest()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<ILogRepository, LogRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton(provider => new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(initialData: new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key: "UseInMemoryDatabase", value: "true"),

            })
            .Build());
         services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Verify_SaveRequestLog()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>())
            {
                context.Set<Log>().Add(new LogRequest());
                var result =await context.SaveAllChangesAsync();
                Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
            }

        }
    }
```

But the unit test method always return 1 and passes, meanwhile the empty object of LogRequest must not save anything to database!
How can I determine not null properties for unit test ? In fact how can I enforce unit test to reflect to validation policies ?

**Update:**

Based on this linke :
[Entity Framework Core Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7228)

that I asked, I got this respond:

> EF Core doesn't do any validation of entities beyond what is needed
>   for internal consistency. Validation is something that could be done
>   in EF, but experience shows that it is not something that is useful to
>   many developers because it usually cannot replace either client-side
>   validation or database validation and there are also other places
>   where validation can be done more effectively.
>
> Going beyond EF to the database, the in-memory database does not
>   currently validate nullability (i.e. requiredness) when saving
>   property values. I will leave this issue open so that we can discuss
>   as a team whether this is something we should add.
>
> Also, if the intent is test with an in-memory database as an
>   approximation for a relational database, then you might want to
>   consider using SQLite in in-memory mode. See
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/index
>   for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this linke :
[Entity Framework Core Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7228)

that I asked, I got my answer :

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                   where e.State == EntityState.Added
                       || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                   select e.Entity;
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
        Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

Comment: this only works for data annotations approach, not if you used fluent API